# How to set Map<String, KClass<out Any>> as property type?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

How can I generate below line of code using Kotlinpoet?

```
val myMap:Map<String, KClass<out Any>>
```

I initialize myMap in init block.

Answer (score 6):

```
Map::class.asClassName()
    .parameterizedBy(
        String::class.asClassName(),
        KClass::class.asClassName().parameterizedBy(WildcardTypeName.producerOf(ANY))
    )
```

Make sure you add the following import:

```
import com.squareup.kotlinpoet.ParameterizedTypeName.Companion.parameterizedBy
```

There's an IDE bug that prevents extension functions declared inside companion objects from being auto-imported, it should get fixed in 1.3.40.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map::class.asClassName()
        .parameterizedBy(String::class.asTypeName(), KClass::class.asClassName().parameterizedBy(TypeVariableName("out Any")))
```